# set variable network layers based on parameters in pytorch

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I want to make the following network definition to a parametric one. The number of continuous and discrete columns varies for different data. I first pass the whole input data, which in this case is 110 dimensional , from a linear with a relu activation. The output of each categorical field of my data varies based on a previous one-hot encoding data transformation. I need to define a nn.Linear(110, number of encodings) for each of them.

```
class Generator(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Generator, self).__init__(110)
    self.lin1 = nn.Linear(110,110)
    self.lin_numerical = nn.Linear(110, 6)
    self.lin_cat_job = nn.Linear(110, 9)
    self.lin_cat_sex = nn.Linear(110, 2)
    self.lin_cat_incomeclass = nn.Linear(110, 7)

  def forward(self, x):
    x = torch.relu(self.lin1(x))
    x_numerical = f.leaky_relu(self.lin_numerical(x))

    x_cat1 = f.gumbel_softmax(self.lin_cat_job(x), tau=0.2)
    x_cat2 = f.gumbel_softmax(self.lin_cat_sex(x), tau=0.2)
    x_cat3 = f.gumbel_softmax(self.lin_cat_incomeclass(x), tau=0.2)

    x_final = torch.cat((x_numerical, x_cat1, x_cat2, x_cat3),1)
    return x_final
```

I have managed to change the **init** part, using discrete_columns input which is an ordereddict that has the name and number of one-hot-encoding of each categorical field of my data as key and values, and continuous_columns which is only a list with the names of the continuous columns. But I have no idea how to edit the forward part:

```
class Generator(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, input_dim, continuous_columns, discrete_columns):
    super(Generator, self).__init__()
    self._input_dim = input_dim
    self._discrete_columns = discrete_columns
    self._num_continuous_columns = len(continuous_columns)

    self.lin1 = nn.Linear(self._input_dim, self._input_dim)
    self.lin_numerical = nn.Linear(self._input_dim, self._num_continuous_columns)

    for key, value in self._discrete_columns.items():
      setattr(self, "lin_cat_{}".format(key), nn.Linear(self._input_dim, value))
    
  def forward(self, x):
    x = torch.relu(self.lin1(x))
    x_numerical = f.leaky_relu(self.lin_numerical(x))
    ####
    This is the problematic part
    #####
    return x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `setattr` and honestly should not since you'd need `getattr`, it brings more trouble than it solves if there's any other ways to do the job.

Now this is what I'd do for this task

```
        self.lin_cat = nn.ModuleDict()
        for key, value in self._discrete_columns.items():
            self.lin_cat[key] = nn.Linear(self._input_dim, value)
        #     setattr(self, "lin_cat_{}".format(key), nn.Linear(self._input_dim, value))

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.relu(self.lin1(x))
        x_numerical = f.leaky_relu(self.lin_numerical(x))

        x_cat = []
        for key in self.lin_cat:
            x_cat.append(f.gumbel_softmax(self.lin_cat[key](x), tau=0.2))
        x_final = torch.cat((x_numerical, *x_cat), 1)
        return x
```